# What kind of action is it to sheathe reload 0 ammunition?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, ammunition

Reload 0 means drawing and firing/throwing can be done in the same action. What happens if you have a piece of ammunition in your hand and you don't want to attack with it or drop it? Example of how this could happen are Shuriken with the Returning rune, or Arrow Snatching, if the DM allowed you to keep the arrow instead of throwing it back. Would storing the ammunition require a normal interact action, or does its zero reload reduce that to a free action?

Comment: Where in the rules does it state that it takes an action to sheath something? That's how I've been playing, and I feel like that's correct, but for the life of me I'm unable to actually find that rule... (naturally, I could just be overlooking something obvious)

Comment: @ESCE I don't believe it's said anywhere specific, so you'd use the closest action which is [Interact](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=80) because [Release](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=83) doesn't apply. There is room for table variance... but not much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1-Action Interact

There is no specific ["sheathe" or "stow"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180320/what-action-does-stowing-a-weapon-require) action, so they fall under [Interact](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=80). While it's true [Reload](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=228) 0 reduces the actions needed to draw your ammunition, you are *not using* the Reload property when you are attempting to put something away. It makes no mention of benefiting you any time that you are not attempting to draw and fire/throw the weapon.

Stowing Reload 0 ammunition costs the exact same as if you were putting any weapon away. I'd even say this makes sense; you have your ammunition in a location that is easy to draw and fire, and you want to keep it that way. Being able to draw easily does not necessarily mean being able to stow easily, so you must be (somewhat) careful in how you place the object back within easy reach.

Comment: I was doing some investigation and it seems that there *used* to be a stow action but it got errata'd out. AoN no longer has it for table 6-2, but see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167051/what-is-the-action-economy-cost-of-drawing-a-weapon-what-about-two/167065#167065). It used be explicitly mentioned here as stowing, but now it only calls out putting away a worn item. My 1st edition CRB also aligns with the screenshot in the linked question.

Comment: @ESCE I thought I remembered that being a thing. That must have been part of the sweeping inventory changes that removed the bandolier, belt pouch, satchel, scroll case, sheath, and vial items.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the [reload rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=228) that specifies that it takes less actions to sheathe an arrow or any other component used in a reload 0 weapon (such as a shuriken). So, by the rules as written, they'd have to stowed just like any other held item (what action that requires is a bit unclear, as Ifusaso points out in the comments, but an Interact action is the accepted standard and what your table seems to be using, so an Interact action would be required in this case).