# What action does stowing a weapon require?

Tags: actions, pathfinder-2e, errata

The rules used to be fairly clear on this point, but they seem to have been errata'd into a more ambiguous state on this matter. Currently there doesn't seem to be strict guidance as to what it takes to stow a held item (like a weapon), as it is no longer mentioned in the [wielding item rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194). However, 1st edition Core Rulebooks (such as mine) used to say it took an Interact to stow an item ([this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/167065/64464) has a now-dated screenshot from Archive of Nethys showing the pre-errata table).

After the errata, is it clear what action it takes to stow a held item, such as a weapon?

(inspired by discussion around [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180314/what-kind-of-action-is-it-to-sheathe-reload-0-ammunition?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C14.2590))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1-Action Interact

The table still exists [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194) and the line has been changed to (emphasis added)

> Draw or **put away a worn item**, or pick up an item | [Interact](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=80)

Answer (score 11):

## It takes 1 Interact Action

Delving into the [official errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) (search for Table 6-2 on that page) that accompanied the change, it seems the relevant text was moved to a different section - specifically, the [Carrying and Using Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=186) section. Essentially, an object can be Held, Worn, or Stowed. The middle category includes things like weapon sheathes. It takes (usually) one Interact to change how one is carrying an item (the exception being items stowed in a backpack or sack, as described in Table 6-2 under [Wielding Items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194)). Thus, sheathing a weapon requires one Interact action. Relevant text from the Carrying and Using Items section, with emphasis by me:

> A character carries items in three ways: held, worn, and stowed. Held items are in your hands; a character typically has two hands, allowing them to hold an item in each hand or a single two-handed item using both hands. Worn items are tucked into pockets, belt pouches, bandoliers, **weapon sheaths**, and so forth, and they can be retrieved and returned relatively quickly. Stowed items are in a backpack or a similar container, and they are more difficult to access.

> Drawing a worn item or **changing how you're carrying an item usually requires you to use an Interact action** (though to drop an item, you use the Release action instead). Table 6–2: Changing Equipment lists **some ways** that you might change the items you're holding or carrying, and the number of hands you need to do so.